# accessing variable from service in one component to another component in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a variable testgetinfos which stores an object array  returned from service, I want to use this variable in another component,

Below is the function where I am storing object array from a service, here when i print the output of testgetinfos variable within this function, its as expected

```
samplefunc(var1,var2) {
this.testgetInfoService.retrieveAllinfos(this.var1,this.var2).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.testgetinfos= response;
    this.router.navigate(['sample']) 
    console.log(this.testgetinfos)
  }

)
}
```

The function is part of below component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestgetInfoService } from '../service/data/test-info.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class testinfo {
constructor(
public id: number, 
  public testvar1: string,
  public testvar2: string,
  public testvar3: string

 ){
 }
}
@Component({
 selector: 'app-test-info',
 templateUrl: './test-info.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./test-info.component.css']
})
export class testInfoComponent implements OnInit {
var1=''
var2=''
public test : string [] 
public testinfos : testinfo[]
constructor(
private testInfoService:TestgetInfoService,
private router:Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {

}
samplefunc(var1,var2) {
this.testgetInfoService.retrieveAllinfos(this.var1,this.var2).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.testgetinfos= response;
    this.router.navigate(['sample']) 
    console.log(this.testgetinfos)
  }

)
} 

}
```

Below is the script from "sample" component where I am trying to print the output of testgetinfos variable,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Testinfo } from '../test-info/test-info.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-sample',
templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
})
export class sampleComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }
};

ngOnInit() {
this.displayinfo();
}
displayinfo(){
console.log("Gather info")
console.log(this.testinfos)
}
}
```

Comment: where is `samplefunc` declared? Inside sampleComponent or service?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you will have to use the testgetInfoService.retrieveAllinfos() in this second component as well. That seems like the simplest solution. But perhaps your question can be improved to clarify if you're trying to do something different?

Comment: samplefunc is declared in a seperate component. I am retrieving values using service based on input values fed in this component.

Comment: @DillonFlohr thanks for notifiying, i missed to add that component, just updated the same to my question

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your service in the constructor of the component you would like to use the service in , for example. You have a Service named TestService. You want to use this service within your TestComponent. To do so you must use Dependency Injection in the TestComponent, to do this do the following:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.testService.testMethod();
 }
}
```

Comment: I have used the constructor as part of the component where I have  samplefunc, I just updated my question with complete component.   I wanted to use the value stored in the array object "testgetinfos" in another component.